# How to disable manually diagonal scrolling WHILE enable diagonal setContentOffset scroll annimation

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uikit

I am using a collection view.
Although the directionLockEnabled can be set to YES, diagonal scrolling is still enabled.

So I found a solution somewhere:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView  {
    self.offset = self.collectionView.contentOffset;
}

// control scroll to only horizontal & vertical
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView  {
    CGFloat deltaX = ABS(self.offset.x - self.collectionView.contentOffset.x);
    CGFloat deltaY = ABS(self.offset.y - self.collectionView.contentOffset.y);
    if (deltaX != 0 && deltaY != 0) {
        if (deltaX >= deltaY) {
            self.collectionView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.collectionView.contentOffset.x, self.offset.y);
        }
        else    {
            self.collectionView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.offset.x, self.collectionView.contentOffset.y);
        }
    }
}
```

However the side effect is when I call with x, y > 0

```
[self.collectionView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(x, y) animated:animated];
```

It doesn't scroll at all, because of the code block above.

How to deal with this?

Answer (score 4):

To disable manually diagonal scrolling in Swift:

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    self.offset = scrollView.contentOffset        
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let deltaX = abs(self.offset.x - self.collectionView.contentOffset.x)
    let deltaY = abs(self.offset.y - self.collectionView.contentOffset.y)

    if deltaX != 0 && deltaY != 0 {
        if deltaX >= deltaY {
            self.collectionView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: self.collectionView.contentOffset.x, y: self.offset.y)
        } else {
            self.collectionView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: self.offset.x, y: self.collectionView.contentOffset.y)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I figure it out...
scrollView.dragging can differentiate manual scrolling or auto scrolling...

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
collectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

It will disable a user from scrolling, but you will be able to scroll programmatically using

```
collectionView.scrollToItem(at:at:animated:)
```